# How to pass ArrayList<CustomObject> to an activity in another application?

Tags: android, share

I am trying to share data between two applications.. first I thought of saving a file to SD Card then read it.. but this solution won't work.. so I wan woundering if there is a way to send an `ArrayList` of an `Object` that implements `Parcelable`..

what other way could be followed to achieve this?

**NOTE:**
Activities are not within the same application.

Answer (score 8):

`ArrayList` is a `Serializable` class and as such can be placed into an `Intent` so long as your custom object is also `Serializable`.  It'd look something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, YourReceiverActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("YourArrayList", new ArrayList<YourSerializableObject>());
startActivity(intent);
```

Then retrieve it:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
ArrayList<YourSerializableObject> list = 
    (ArrayList<YourSerializableObject>)intent.getSerializableExtra("YourArrayList");
```

For your object to be `Serializable`, all of the contained members need to be `Serializable` as well.

Comment: [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) is serializable and [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) accepts a serializable object.  So long as your ArrayList contains serializable objects, it will accept it.

Comment: I think you should use putSerializable(ArrayList<Obj>) instead of putExtra. Also the OP stated that his class implements parcelable whichof course can be achieved using putParcelableArray().

Answer (score 1):

You may use a static class (called DataChannel for example) with a static member kind of ArrayList< CustomObject>, then use static get/set to pass the object between activities.

Comment: Static approach should be last choice. There is a good way of doing it as pointed by @MCeley

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why no one mentioned this but your best bet is BY FAR SQLite.
It's MUCH more efficient than any object passing as it does not hog any memory in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the array of objects as an extra in an Intent using :

```
public Intent putExtra (String name, Parcelable[] value)
```

You have to configure your other app to receive an Intent for your custom URI.