# How to pass an array of Uri to next Activity ?

Tags: android, arraylist, uri

I've been working around since few days to pass array of Uri that I've stored in ArrayList. I refer to [this document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943873/how-to-pass-an-array-of-uri-between-activity-using-bundle) and [this document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493818/how-to-pass-arraylistcustomobject-to-an-activity-in-another-application) but didn't work well for me. Uri's are adding to the ArrayList but I'm not able to retrieve this array to next Activity so that I can display in a GridView.

Any Help on this ?

Comment: you may use static array list for this...